# Alignment of the caption of the figure below the figure in the two columns text

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I would like to ask how to align the caption of the figure below the figure in the two columns text. I was able to reduce figure into the column width but the caption is still spreaded on the whole page (please see the picture and code below).
Thank you very much for the help.

Code:

```
 \begin{figure*}[!htb]  
   \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,left]{example1.PNG}
   \caption[\columnwidth]{Box appeared to be the only solution to place these four images in two columns, but what happens now is that pictures are shifted and overlapping the second column and the caption remains in the first column:}
   \label{fig:view10} 
\end{figure*}
```

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` instead of `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` and also should use caption as `\caption{...}`

Comment: you are using `figure*` so a full page figure spanning two columns (the `[!htb]` is wrong as such figures do not support `h` or `b`  use `figure`

Comment: BTW: Usually the optional argument of `\caption` is the text to be used in the list of figures. It is not a length. So if this works in your case, it seems you are using some code, that redefines `\caption` very unusually. This makes your code even more inreproducible and would be one more reason to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of a code snippet.